# Is `render` method called only when `state` changes or on `props` change as well?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I was exploring how `componentWillReceiveProps` method works in React. I found out that this method is called when any of the `props` changes for a component and this method can be used to update state of the component using `setState` method, which will then result in the component getting re-rendered.

But if I do not call `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps`, will it result in `render` not being called. In other words, is `render` called only when state changes, not when props change?

Comment: Render is always called when `state` or `props` change. `componentWillReceiveProps` used to be the way you could do something with the props before the render occurred. It is currently `UNSAFE` however, and [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is recommended instead. For most use cases you don't even need to put props in state, since you could just use them before rendering in the actual `render` method.

Comment: you shouldn't rely on `props` for re-render your component but you should be using state for re-rendering instead http://lucybain.com/blog/2016/react-state-vs-pros/

Answer (score 3):

Your thoughts are slightly off track.

The function `componentWillReceiveProps` is called every time there is an update. It's a functional state that occurs before your changes actually gets dispatched to the DOM.

So, when you are using `componentWillReceiveProps`, you're actually in the middle of the execution tree and defining your own custom behavior that should happen before the update to take place.

In simple words, `componentWillReceiveProps` will get triggered every time if

1. For the child component when the parent component causes the prop of the child component to change
2. The component itself receives new props.

**EDIT**

Answering your comment, if any change causes a component to re-render, all components defined under it that is all its child components will also re-render

If you need a detailed answer as to what prompts such a change, search for the reconciliation algorithm of react

Comment: Thanks for responding Aseem. But I am confused about whether `render` method is called when only props change, but there's no state change. Or it will be called only if I call `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: If your parent render is called, the child render will also be called as the whole tree below the parent is re-rendered

Comment: Thanks @Aseem. I'm going through the concepts you have mentioned.

Comment: "In simple words, componentWillReceiveProps gets called every time the state and props change." This is not true. The [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) clearly states that "UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. Calling this.setState() generally doesn’t trigger UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()."

Comment: that's like taking things out of context. but i'll edit the answer anyway

Comment: @Tholle hope the simple words answer fits now